# Macbook 3,1 (2007 White Model) works slow and lags

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, repair

For the past year my Macbook has be getting slower, lauder and lags constantly...
The lags range from switching spaces to changing a language or even typing an input.
It almost never craches, but it does seem like his age is catching up to him...

I have tried formatting it completely already. I bought it with Leopard, and went through Snow Leopard to Lion. It got this way before the Lion installation (which I hoped would help), and now after completely reformatting my into Lion, it took only a few days for it to come back to this condition.

What can I do to make my Mac work right again?

Comment: When did this start - with Lion? How much RAM do you have? Did you try a SMC reset? An SMC reset should be applied if the computer is running unusually slowly although it is not experiencing abnormally high CPU utilization. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

Comment: How much space do you have left on your hard disk? As the disk approaches full things slow down. If the disk is getting full consider replacing it with a bigger one.

Comment: Like above, how much free space do you have left? From how you describe it, this could be a failing hard drive. Not a catastrophic failure, but a gradual one.

Comment: I know about the harddrive case. Ever since I formatted my Mac I had lots of free space.. I have 2GB RAM. I did not try an SMC reset. And @Matt, as I said above, it started way before Lion...